# Django is taking the templates from virtualenv not from /templates for application

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.2.10 and I also use a template for frontend and for admin panel. My problem is that the website is loading the templates from virtualenv and not from the template folders in the applications. My current configuration is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'apps.admin_volt.apps.AdminVoltConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'apps.app',
'apps.crypto',
'apps.taskmgr',
'django_celery_results',
'apps.home',
'apps.authentication',
'debug_toolbar',]

CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, "core/templates")  # ROOT dir for crypto

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
...

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'core/static'),
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'apps/admin_volt/static'),
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'apps/static'),
)
```

How can I change my configuration to ensure that the templates are taken from app/admin_volt/templates/admin and not from venv\Lib\site-packages\admin_volt\templates\admin

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what package you are using?  I see in your installed apps that you have 
'apps.admin_volt.apps.AdminVoltConfig', is this just where you have templates that you intend to override the default templates?  Please share the source of this package or take a look at the docs and see if it has a way to override template packs.  It seems like it comes pre-loaded with Bootstrap 5 templates.

Comment: This is the package that I am using: https://github.com/app-generator/django-admin-volt